# Disabling background color for WKInterfaceSwitch

Tags: apple-watch, watchos-2, wkinterfaceswitch

When I use a WKInterfaceSwitch, watchOS draws a translucent background behind the entire control. I don't want this background to appear, but haven't been able to find any ways to hide or disable it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way to completely disable it either but if you put the switch in a group and set the group's background color, you can change the color. It still has an overlay tint on it but I guess it's better than nothing

You can may have an issue with the corner radius. You just need to set the corner radius of the group to 6.0 which is the default for a group https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacegroup/1619667-setcornerradius?language=objc

```
[self.groupSwitchHolder setCornerRadius:6.0];
```